# How does index of an array work in postgresql?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have this function in postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_values(vals numeric[])
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'value: --%',vals[0];
    RAISE NOTICE 'value: --%',vals[1];
    RAISE NOTICE 'value: --%',vals[2];
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And strangely while calling this function, the index of the array started from 1 not 0

```
select get_values(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```

OR

```
select get_values('{1,2,3}');
```

output:

```
NOTICE:  value: --<NULL>
NOTICE:  value: --1
NOTICE:  value: --2
 get_values
------------
```

The index of an array starts from 1 in postgresql?

Comment: Strangely? I guess you didn't bother to read [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING).

Comment: I don't know what's strange about that. I for one start counting at 1 as well if I count things.

Comment: @mu is too short   I only used the word strange because, I learned from these programming languages like C,C++ and Java that the index of an array starts from 0. But yes, I did not check the documentation, I thought SO would be much faster than going through documentation. But nonetheless Thanks for the comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the chapter "Accessing arrays" in the manual, it's right there:

> *By default PostgreSQL uses a **one-based** numbering convention for arrays, that is, an array of n elements starts with array[1] and ends with array[n]*

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Taken from: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING